# What will become of [asp.net-5] and [entity-framework-7] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx

It seems they are renaming asp.net 5 to asp.net core 1.0 and .net core, and entity framework 7 is now entity framework core 1.0 or EF core 1.0.

What will become of the existing tags? Move on, or rename?

Comment: We should probably wait two weeks, as they'll just rebrand it again.

Comment: David Fowler guaranteed me by 98.578% that the name is fixed now and that no amount of complaints about the name will make them change it again.

Comment: the tag `asp.net-vnext` is also obsolete!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Core is a new product, not backwards compatible.  Notably, it lacks webforms, which was the heart of ASP.NET 1.  The same goes for MVC Core.  It can't run on ASP.NET 4x, so it is not backwards compatible with MVC 5.

The problem becomes this--it's completely forseeable that MS releases an ASP.NET version 5 that *is* backwards compatible.  The rebranding of these non-backwards compatible rewrites allows for this.

So, while we should definitely make sure people asking about Core tag correctly, we shouldn't merge ASP.NET 5 into ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Good luck with that!

Comment: This question only deals with ASP.NET **5** (and Entity Framework **7**) which are the open source projects started from scratch. Neither of them are backwards-compatible to ASP.NET 4 or EF6. But that doesn’t change the fact that this is really just a *rename* from ASP.NET 5 to ASP.NET Core. Every question that deals with ASP.NET 5 (the *open source framework*) **is** about ASP.NET Core. It is the same thing.

Comment: @poke as I stated, they rebranded to Code because it's a different product.  Nothing--absolutely nothing--would prevent MS from releasing an updated version of ASP.NET 4x that *is* backwards compatible, which means we could very well have ASP.NET 5 *and* ASP.NET Core.

Comment: And how does that in any way affect the questions that are tagged *now* with ASP.NET 5? We want to rename the tag, so those questions will be correctly sorted as ASP.NET Core instead of an ASP.NET 5 which as of now no longer exists (officially).

Comment: @poke It's important that we be very distinct that ASP.NET 5 is NOT Core.  If it was, we could just merge the tags together, but we can't because they aren't the same.  Some people have mistagged core questions, and they need fixing.  That's the distinction that I wish to highlight.

Comment: @poke Welp... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315270/asp-net-5-ef7-tags-incorrectly-synonymized

Comment: WebForms was only at the beginning the heart of ASP.NET. Has been changed after ASP.NET MVC 3. And now thanks god WebForms is gone!

Answer (score 3):

Since ASP.NET 5 is just being renamed to ASP.NET Core, while everything else still applies to the new thing (minus refactoring things which we already had to deal with during the whole beta time), we should just rename the tags:

- [asp.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-5) becomes [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core)
- [asp.net-mvc-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-6) becomes [asp.net-core-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc)
- [entity-framework-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-7) becomes [entity-framework-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core)
- The old tag [asp.net-vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-vnext) also becomes [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core)

So every question that already exists with one of these tags should just be adjusted so that the new tag name is used (I’m not sure if we can just *rename* the tags without having to retag every question—we hopefully can!). After all, they deal with the same thing, and nothing apart from the name changed. Since the questions usually mention their version anyway (whether it’s a beta or a RC version), we probably won’t have an issue with older questions affecting the release versions later.

In general, we want to avoid adding additional version specifiers unless they are needed. So once one of those projects ends up with a version 2, it might make sense to create additional tags like [asp.net-core-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-1.x) and [asp.net-core-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-2.x) when dealing with *version specific* things; similar to how we deal with [python-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

Comment: `asp.net-vnext` should also become `asp.net-core`

Comment: @M4N Agreed! Added it to the list, thanks :)

Comment: This isn't correct.  It isn't a rebranding, it's a different product--it's not backwards compatible.  That's part of the reason for the rebranding.

Comment: @Will It *is* backwards compatible to ASP.NET 5, because it is the exact same thing.

Comment: @poke nope.  You can't upgrade your webforms 4x application to 5.

Comment: @Will Exactly. So every **existing question** about ASP.NET 5 is actually about ASP.NET Core. Which is why we want to rename those tags; the product name changed!

Comment: If the tag is incorrect, then it should be fixed, agreed.

Comment: @Will That’s what this question is about: “What happens to the *existing* ASP.NET 5 related tags” – “We should rename them to reflect the new name.”

Comment: I've renamed the tags (leaving synonyms in place); caching can cause tag pages to still be listing old counts for a little while.

Comment: Hi folks, this is Eilon Lipton, engineering manager of ASP.NET and Entity Framework. This rename wrong and the synonyms are misleading. The concept of ASP.NET 5 is *not* the same as ASP.NET Core 1. Though we did rename the product, they are not synonyms. We specifically renamed the product to indicate that this is an offshoot, as opposed to simply a rename. Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315270/asp-net-5-ef7-tags-incorrectly-synonymized

Comment: @Eilon I’m well aware that ASP.NET Core is *not* the same as a hypothetical ASP.NET 5. This question was mostly about making sure that all *existing* questions will have the correct tag with the renamed products. So renaming the tag was without doubt the correct action. As for the synonyms that were added, you should see this as a temporary means. As of right now, ASP.NET 5 and ASP.NET Core are synonymous. If you download it, you still get “ASP.NET 5 RC1” and that is the name that is still used mostly on the official sites too. The name migration started but is naturally slow, and it will […]

Comment: […] take a while, likely until after the release of RC2, before the new name reached everyone (and the fact that ASP.NET 5 is no longer). Similarly, a lot online resources only talk about ASP.NET 5 right now; not Core. I guess you take part of the blame for this naming mess, and you should know that blindly ignoring the old name “ASP.NET 5” would be a very stupid move now. That is the old name, and people will continue to use that name for a while. Until then, the synonyms make total sense.

Comment: @poke I think the synonyms being temporary wasn't clear to me, and I want to make sure that the synonyms are not permanent. That is, that there is a specific plan on when the synonyms will be removed.

Comment: @Eilon There is no specific plan for the removal, but I always considered them temporary (but also essential for this phase). When we get to RTM, I guess we can talk about removing the synonyms.

Answer (score -1):

ASP.Net Core 1.0 is the new name of Asp.net 5 and the ASP.NET-5 tag no longer makes sense and should be renamed.

Same for entity framework for DNX.  Similarly questions using the old nomenclature should be updated with a note to state "This is about ASP.NET Core (formerly called ASP.NET 5)".  Microsoft has now switched to referring to everything as:

- .NET Core  - The portable framework
- ASP.NET Core - ASP.NET on .NET Core
- EF Core  - EF on .NET Core

Rename ASP.NET-5 to ASP.NET-CORE

Rename Entity-framework-7 to ENTITY-FRAMEWORK-CORE

Leave the 1 off because the numbers may change rapidly.  do we want tags for 1.1 or 1.0.1 or 2.0?  I don't think it makes sense in the case of ASP.NET CORE and .NET CORE to track the 1.0/2.0 generations.     The shift to ASP.NET-CORE-2.0 is likely to be a marketing shift not a technical shift anyways, and thus for technical questions, having a -1 suffix isn't that useful. But if we must be utterly consistent, I guess we can have both the ASP.NET-CORE and ASP.NET-CORE1 tags.

Exhibits:

[Example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820947/whats-the-difference-between-asp-net-5-net-core-and-asp-net-core-5) edited to show the body changes I suggest, which has not had the tags changed yet, obviously.  I do NOT suggest we delete all body-text references to "ASP.NET 5" but rather amend these questions so that the rename is obvious to all readers.

Comment: *“ASP.Net Core 1.0 is "NOT" Asp.net 5”* – Not sure what you’re trying to say with that. Every existing question about ASP.NET 5 is about ASP.NET Core (since it’s just a new name but everything else stays the same, minues refactoring).

Comment: *“The shift to ASP.NET-CORE-2.0 is likely to be a marketing shift”* – Not true at all. All .NET Core related things (so including ASP.NET Core) will follow [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), so the versioning will be *very closely* related to technical changes.

Comment: So rename tag. Not clear?

Comment: You're contradicting yourself.  “ASP.Net Core 1.0 is "NOT" Asp.net 5” is correct, and that's why the tag shouldn't be renamed.  There is a possibility that there will be an ASP.NET 5 that's backwards compatible with the 4x stack.  Core is a new, not backwards compatible product.  So definitely tag core questions with core, but nothing says ASP.NET 5 will not exist.  This is going to be super confusing for awhile.

Comment: Actually that's NOT correct.  It is literally true that Microsoft intends .net core to totally (over time) replace all classic .net .3 and .net 4 technologies including the current asp.net mvc 4 which will probably NEVER receive a major +1.0 version bump again