# Rename [asp.net-5] tag to [asp.net-core]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Microsoft has just announced that the heretofore named ASP.NET 5 will be summarily renamed to ASP.NET Core, version 1.

Could we get a moderator to rename the [asp.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-5) tag to [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core)? We would then need to create a synonym for asp.net-5 to asp.net-core.

See: *[ASP.NET 5 is dead - Introducing ASP.NET Core 1.0 and .NET Core 1.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx)*

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315077/what-will-become-of-asp-net-5-and-entity-framework-7-tags