# ASP.NET Core name change; should the questions and answers be edited too?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I've seen the [discussions around the tag changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315077/what-will-become-of-asp-net-5-and-entity-framework-7-tags), but should we also be editing the titles and contents of the questions and answers themselves to reflect the name change from ASP.NET 5 to ASP.NET Core 1?

I'm not suggesting a mass-renaming exercise, I'm more thinking about when we find existing questions as part of regular use of the site?

Comment: Only fix it if you run into them...

Comment: ... and fix any other problems you see in the post :).

Comment: No, a moderator just needs to create a tag synonym.