# Can we disambiguate the [asp.net5] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

A few months ago we had [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400924/net-5-0-and-asp-net-core-5-0-tags) about future treatment of the [ASP].NET [Core] 5.0 tags, since Microsoft changed their naming scheme once again: The next version of ".NET Core 3.1" will be ".NET 5".

One of the discussed points was the name for the next release of the ASP.NET Core framework, where [Microsoft went for ASP.NET **Core** 5.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five):

> ASP.NET Core 5.0 is based on .NET 5.0 but retains the name "Core" to avoid confusing it with ASP.NET MVC 5.

There already has been a tag [asp.net5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net5) for years, which was mainly used for ASP.NET Core 1.0 questions, before the new "Core" naming became commonly known. It was also (mis)used for questions related to ASP.NET MVC 5, which, if I understood correctly, should have gone to the [asp.net-mvc-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-5) tag instead. Note that there also was an [asp.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-5) tag (mind the dash), which has been [synonymized in 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315077/what-will-become-of-asp-net-5-and-entity-framework-7-tags) to point to [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core).

---

Nowadays, the [asp.net5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net5) tag is being misused for questions about ASP.NET Core 5.0. When I checked the tag shortly after the .NET 5 release, I noticed that it had already accumulated a few mistagged questions, which I subsequently fixed/closed. To reduce the increasing influx of such mistagged questions, I also proposed two edits to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36624255/revisions) and [tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36624256/revisions), which point to the [asp.net-core-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-5.0) tag.

However, this did not do much, and there are still mistagged questions coming in. I refrained from further retagging myself, and decided to wait for community consensus.

A long-term solution for this tag would be nice. Simply synonymizing the [asp.net5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net5) tag won't work, since its questions are about three different technologies: ASP.NET MVC 5, ASP.NET 5 -> ASP.NET Core 1.0, and now ASP.NET Core 5.0. A full burnination might be the cleanest solution, to stop the usage of that ambiguous tag at all.

---

**I'd propose to do the following:**

- Retag all (classic) ASP.NET MVC 5 questions with [asp.net-mvc-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-5).
- Retag all >1 year old "ASP.NET 5" questions with [asp.net-core-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-1.0) (or just [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core), if a question isn't version-specific).
- Retag all younger questions with the [asp.net-core-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-5.0) tag, if they are clearly about this version.
- Fix/close/delete off-topic questions, and clean up the good ones.

At the moment, the tag has 336 questions (98 when I asked this meta question).

Answer (score 2):

I agree, the tag should be avoided since it causes a lot of confusion. Microsoft thankfully stuck with “ASP.NET Core” for its future versions, so the disambiguation between the modern ASP.NET Core and the legacy ASP.NET (MVC or not) relies on the existence of that “Core” part. As such, a tag that does not include it but likely still refers to it is highly confusing.

I would also agree with your plan to simply retag the existing questions. ~200 questions isn’t that high of a number, and we likely have to evaluate individually anyway what the question is actually about. I would just adjust one part about it: Younger questions, which are likely about ASP.NET Core 5.0 shouldn’t get the [asp.net-core-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-5.0) tag by default. We should still evaluate whether it’s actually version-specific or not. In most cases, it probably won’t. And if we decide to use the [asp.net-core-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-5.0) tag, we should also include the version-unspecific one [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) as well.

I’m not familiar with how the burnination process works exactly, but I would just suggest that we start retagging those questions soon anyway. Once we have the number down, we can get rid of the tag.